# Understanding automatic CSI migration

Tags: kubernetes, devops, openshift, persistent-volume-claims, csi

As in-tree plug-ins are going to be deprecated, third party storage provider is installed as default in the Kubernetes cluster. So my doubt is if I don’t enable automatic CSI migration, what will happen if I create new workloads with pvc using CSI driver? And what will happen to my existing workload which is using in-tree plugins. Quite confused on what is the exact use of automatic CSI migration

Answer (score 0):

If you don't enable automatic CSI migration, existing workloads that utilize PVCs backed by in-tree drivers will continue to use the in-tree driver.When enabled, any new workloads that use a CSI driver will automatically be migrated to the new CSI driver.The purpose of automatic CSI migration in Kubernetes is to replace existing in-tree storage plugins with a corresponding CSI driver.

If automatic CSI migration is not enabled and new workloads are created with PVCs using a CSI driver, the workloads will still be able to use the in-tree storage plugin. However, they will not be able to take advantage of any features provided by the CSI driver. It recommends that you enable automatic CSI migration to ensure that your workloads are running on the most up-to-date and optimized storage plugins.

CSI migration is to migrate existing workloads from in-tree storage plugins to CSI-based storage plugins.The new CSI-based plugins will be able to take advantage of the improved features and improved performance that comes with the new plugins.

For reference follow the [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/09/26/storage-in-tree-to-csi-migration-status-update-1.25/).

Comment: But I have both CSI driver storage class and in tree storage class in my cluster. So if I create CSI driver based PVC, then I should be able to use CSI features right?

Comment: In your use case there is a chance of getting issues between different drivers, ensure that all PVCs that do not require any special storage class are provisioned by the installed CSI driver, and that the default StorageClass is explicitly annotated on PVCs
and if both storage classes are using the same storage provider, the performance of the cluster may be negatively impacted as the storage driver will have to manage both storage classes